# How Can I Post Fetch Data from an External Server to My Express Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I have an ExpressJS server built on NodeJS which I'm trying to POST to using `fetch()` and a route file named `test`. I have a form on my external website that needs to submit data to the server. When testing this, I receive the following error in the console:

```
submit.html:228 OPTIONS https://domain/test 0 ()
setOutcome @ submit.html:228
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ submit.html:272
Error:  TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

This is the `fetch()` statement, which works fine in other examples when used in files hosted on the Express server where my domain is, just not when trying to fetch externally:

```
fetch('https://domain/test', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        data: 'test'
    })
})
```

Should I be using `fetch()` to communicate with my Express server externally or should I be using something else? Sorry, I am new to this and trying to find my feet.

Additionally, I can't see that the server has even received a request in my server log files. If doing this on the Express server, I'll normally see a `GET` or `POST` in the logs.

Comment: If your on the same domain, just do -> `fetch("/test")`.  cross origin requests will do a pre-flight OPTION request.

Comment: @Keith - I have solved this using CORS and testing from a production server. Thanks for your response.